# How to get value list from generic dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I've used this [ObjectPool](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/genericidenetiymapobjectpool01262008090822am/genericidenetiymapobjectpool.aspx?login=true&user=kfinke) class as the basis of my Identity Map.  However, I need to bring back the list of all objects of a type.  Matthew has :

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
    {
        Type myType = typeof(T);

        if (!m_pool.ContainsKey(myType))
            return new T[0];

        return m_pool[myType].Values as IEnumerable<T>;
    }
```

However, when I make changes to the client like so:

```
        pool.AddItem<Animal>(dog.ID, dog);
        pool.AddItem<Vegetable>(carrot.Identifier, carrot);
        pool.AddItem<Vegetable>(greenbean.Identifier, greenbean);
        pool.AddItem<Mineral>(carbon.UniqueID, carbon);

        Console.WriteLine("Dog is in the pool -- this statement is " + pool.ContainsKey<Animal>(dog.ID));

        IEnumerable<Vegetable> veggies = pool.GetItems<Vegetable>();
        foreach(Vegetable veg in veggies)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", veg.Color, veg.IsTasty));
```

veggies is null.  It would appear that m_pool[myType].Values does not support the cast to IEnumerable.

I've tried a few things, for example:

```
        IDictionary<int, T> dic = (IDictionary<int, T>) m_pool[myType];
        ICollection<T> values = (ICollection<T>)dic.Values;
```

However, I always end up with a casting error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that `GetItems` method is *never* going to work, seeing as `Dictionary<int, object>.Values` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` unless `T` is `object`. Shame that the method is so fundamentally broken - oh for some unit tests.

I suggest you check the licence, and if you can fix `GetItems`, do so:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
{
    Type myType = typeof(T);

    IDictionary<int, object> dictionary;

    if (!m_pool.TryGetValue(myType, out dictionary))
    {
        return new T[0];
    }

    return dictionary.Values.Cast<T>();
}
```

That's if you're using .NET 3.5 (you'll need `using System.Linq` as well, to get the `Cast` extension method). Let me know if you need something for .NET 2.0.

Comment: Any advantages of using `new T[0]` over `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`? I'm asking merely out of curiosity.

Comment: None really. I just reused as much of the code as possible :) (It was probably written pre-LINQ.)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following ObjectPool ( the code is not mine I just added couple of methods ) ( if you do not use log4net replace logger.Info with Console.WriteLine ; )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reflection;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config; 


namespace DH
{

    //DH - DataHolders
    /// <summary>
    /// This class models a storage structure for objects queriable by id 
    /// </summary>
    public class ObjectPool
    {

        #region Props
        private int totalCount;
        public int TotalCount
        {
            get
            {
                return totalCount;
            }
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }


        #endregion Props


        public ObjectPool ()
        {
            m_pool = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Int32, Object>> ();
        }


        private Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Int32, Object>> m_pool;

        public void AddItem<T> ( Int32 pID, T value )
        {
            Type myType = typeof ( T );

            if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
            {
                m_pool.Add ( myType, new Dictionary<int, object> () );
                m_pool[myType].Add ( pID, value );

                totalCount++;
                return;
            }

            if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
            {
                m_pool[myType].Add ( pID, value );
                totalCount++;
                return;
            }

            m_pool[myType][pID] = value;
            totalCount++;
            //Utils.Debugger.WriteIf("Adding 1 to pool count , pool count is " + this.totalCount);
        }


        public void AddItem<T> ( T value )
        {
            Int32 pID = totalCount ;
            Type myType = typeof ( T );

            if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
            {
                m_pool.Add ( myType, new Dictionary<int, object> () );
                m_pool[myType].Add ( pID, value );

                totalCount++;
                return;
            }

            if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
            {
                m_pool[myType].Add ( pID, value );
                totalCount++;
                return;
            }

            m_pool[myType][pID] = value;
            totalCount++;
            //Utils.Debugger.WriteIf("Adding 1 to pool count , pool count is " + this.totalCount);
        }


        public bool RemoveItem<T> ( Int32 pID )
        {
            Type myType = typeof ( T );

            if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
                return false;

            if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
                return false;

            totalCount--;
            return m_pool[myType].Remove ( pID );
        }

        public bool ContainsKey<T> ( Int32 pID )
        {
            Type myType = typeof ( T );

            if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
                return false;

            if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
                return false;

            return m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID );
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T> ()
        {
            Type myType = typeof ( T );

            if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
                return new T[0];

            return m_pool[myType].Values as IEnumerable<T>;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="pID">The p ID.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="KeyNotFoundException"></exception>
        public T GetItem<T> ( Int32 pID )
        {
            // will throw KeyNotFoundException if either of the dictionaries 
            // does not hold the required key
            return (T)m_pool[typeof ( T )][pID];
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="strPropMetaName"> the string representation of the </param>
        /// <param name="strPropValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T GetItemByPropertyValue<T> ( String strPropMetaName , String strPropValue)
        {
            Type myType = typeof ( T );

            for (int i = 0; i < this.TotalCount; i++)
            {
                if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
                {
                    return default ( T );
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.ContainsKey<T> ( i ))
                    {
                        //get an item object having the same type
                        T item = this.GetItem<T> ( i );

                        //if the object has the same property -- check its value
                        MemberInfo[] members = myType.GetMembers ();
                        for (int j = 0; j < members.Length; j++)
                        {
                            logger.Info ( "members[j].Name is " + members[j].Name );
                            //logger.Info ( ".MemberType.ToString() " + members[j].MemberType.ToString () );
                            //logger.Info ( "members[j].GetType().ToString() " + members[j].GetType ().ToString () );
                            //logger.Info ( " members[j].ToString () is " + members[j].ToString () );
                            //logger.Info ( " members[j].ToString () is " + members[j] );


                            if (members[j].Name.ToString ().Equals ( strPropMetaName ))
                            {


                                FieldInfo[] fi;
                                fi = myType.GetFields ( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );


                                foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
                                {
                                    //logger.Info ( "f.GetValue( obj ) is " + f.GetValue ( item ) );
                                    if ( f.GetValue ( item ).ToString().Equals(strPropValue))
                                        return (T)m_pool[typeof ( T )][i];
                                    else 
                                        continue ;

                                } //eof foreach                             
                            }
                            else
                                continue;
                        } //eof for j

                    } //eof if 
                    else
                        continue;
                } //eof else if m_pool.ContainsKey
            }
            return default ( T );
        }


        private static readonly ILog logger =
LogManager.GetLogger ( typeof ( DH.ObjectPool ) );

    } //eof class pool  

} //eof namespace



namespace PoolSample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
LogManager.GetLogger ( typeof ( Program ) );

        public static DH.ObjectPool pool = new DH.ObjectPool ();

        static void Main ( string[] args )
        {
            DOMConfigurator.Configure (); //tis configures the logger 

            Animal dog = new Animal () { Name = "Fido", ID = 1 };
            Vegetable carrot = new Vegetable { Color = "Orange", Identifier = 2, IsTasty = true };
            Mineral carbon = new Mineral () { UniqueID = 3, IsPoisonousToAnimal = false , Name="some"};
            HolderForStrings hfs = new HolderForStrings () { ID = 4, Value = "user_name", MetaName = "meta_nam" };
            HolderForStrings hfs1 = new HolderForStrings () { ID = 5, Value = "user_name", MetaName = "hfs1" };
            Mineral carbon1 = new Mineral () { UniqueID = 3, IsPoisonousToAnimal = false, Name = "some1" };

            pool.AddItem ( dog );
            pool.AddItem ( carrot );
            pool.AddItem ( hfs );
            pool.AddItem ( hfs1 );


            //pool.AddItem<Animal>(dog.ID, dog);
            //pool.AddItem<Vegetable>(carrot.Identifier, carrot);
            //pool.AddItem<Mineral> ( carbon );
            //pool.AddItem<HolderForStrings> ( 1, hfs );



            //logger.Info("Dog is in the pool -- this statement is " + pool.ContainsKey<Animal>(dog.ID));
            //logger.Info("hfs is in the pool -- this statement is " + pool.ContainsKey<HolderForStrings>(hfs.ID));
            //logger.Info("The hfs value is from the poos is " + pool.GetItem<HolderForStrings>(4).Value);


            //logger.Info("poo.GetItems is " + pool.GetItems<HolderForStrings>());
            #region while
            //for (int i = 0; i < pool.Count -1 ; i++)
            int i = 1;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    logger.Info ( "counting" );
                    logger.Info ( " i is " + i.ToString () );
                    if (pool.ContainsKey<Animal> ( i ))
                    {
                        logger.Info ( " I see animal which is " + pool.GetItem<Animal> ( i ).Name );
                    }

                    if (pool.ContainsKey<Vegetable> ( i ))
                    {
                        logger.Info ( " I see Vegetable which is " + pool.GetItem<Vegetable> ( i ).Color );
                    }


                    if (pool.ContainsKey<Mineral> ( i ))
                    {
                        logger.Info ( " I see Mineral which is " + pool.GetItem<Mineral> ( i ).IsPoisonousToAnimal );
                    }


                    if (pool.ContainsKey<HolderForStrings> ( i ))
                    {
                        logger.Info ( " I see string which is " + pool.GetItem<HolderForStrings> ( i ).Value );
                    }

                    //logger.Info("pool.GetItem<HolderForStrings>(4).Value); is " + pool.GetItem<Object>(i).ToString());

                    i = i + 1;
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
                {
                    continue;
                }

            } //eof for 
            while (i < pool.TotalCount);
#endregion while
            #region AddHolders
            ////this is the success identifier
            //HoldInt16 holdVerifier = new HoldInt16()
            //{
            //  ID=0 ,
            //  MetaName = "ret",
            //  Value = 0
            //};
            //pool.AddItem<HoldInt16>(holdVerifier.ID, holdVerifier);

            //ListDictionary lidMetaName = pool.LidMetaName;
            ////this is the message
            //HoldString holdMsg = new HoldString( ref lidMetaName)
            //{
            //  ID=1,
            //  MetaName = "msg",
            //  Value = msg,
            //  Title = "title" 
            //};
            //pool.AddItem<HoldString>(holdMsg.ID, holdMsg);


            //HoldString holdmmsg = new HoldString(ref lidMetaName)
            //{
            //  ID=2,
            //  MetaName = "mmsg",
            //  Value = "mmsg" , 
            //  Title = "title" 
            //};
            #endregion AddHolders


            //Utils.Debugger.DebugListDictionary(ref msg, "domainName", ref lidMetaName);

            //get the value be metaName

            logger.Info ( "I queried the pool by property with meta Value and value user_name " );

            HolderForStrings HolderForStrings = pool.GetItemByPropertyValue<HolderForStrings> ( "MetaName", "hfs1" );
            //logger.Info ( "object dump" + Utils.Log.ObjDumper.DumpObject ( HolderForStrings ) );
            logger.Info ( "I found the following value for property with the name \"Name\" " );
            logger.Info ( HolderForStrings.MetaName);

            Console.ReadLine ();







        } //eof Main

    } //eof class 

    public class Animal
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HolderForStrings
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
        public String MetaName { get; set; }
        Type ObjType = typeof ( string );
        public Int32 Size { get; set; }
        public bool IsOptional { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }

    } //eof class


    public class Vegetable
    {
        public Int32 Identifier { get; set; }
        public String Color { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsTasty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mineral
    {
        public Int32 UniqueID { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsPoisonousToAnimal { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; } 
    }

    #region classObjectPool
    //public class ObjectPool
    //{
    //  public int Count
    //  {
    //    get { return m_pool.Count; }
    //  }

    //  public ObjectPool ()
    //  {
    //    m_pool = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Int32, Object>> ();
    //  }

    //  private Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Int32, Object>> m_pool;

    //  public void AddItem<T> ( Int32 pID, T value )
    //  {
    //    Type myType = typeof ( T );

    //    if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
    //    {
    //      m_pool.Add ( myType, new Dictionary<int, object> () );
    //      m_pool[myType].Add ( pID, value );
    //      return;
    //    }

    //    if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
    //    {
    //      m_pool[myType].Add ( pID, value );
    //      return;
    //    }

    //    m_pool[myType][pID] = value;
    //  }

    //  public bool RemoveItem<T> ( Int32 pID )
    //  {
    //    Type myType = typeof ( T );

    //    if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
    //      return false;

    //    if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
    //      return false;

    //    return m_pool[myType].Remove ( pID );
    //  }

    //  public bool ContainsKey<T> ( Int32 pID )
    //  {
    //    Type myType = typeof ( T );

    //    if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
    //      return false;

    //    if (!m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID ))
    //      return false;

    //    return m_pool[myType].ContainsKey ( pID );
    //  }

    //  public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T> ()
    //  {
    //    Type myType = typeof ( T );

    //    if (!m_pool.ContainsKey ( myType ))
    //      return new T[0];

    //    return m_pool[myType].Values as IEnumerable<T>;
    //  }

    //  /// <summary>
    //  /// Gets the item.
    //  /// </summary>
    //  /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    //  /// <param name="pID">The p ID.</param>
    //  /// <returns></returns>
    //  /// <exception cref="KeyNotFoundException"></exception>
    //  public T GetItem<T> ( Int32 pID )
    //  {
    //    // will throw KeyNotFoundException if either of the dictionaries 
    //    // does not hold the required key
    //    return (T)m_pool[typeof ( T )][pID];
    //  }

    //} //eof pool  
    #endregion

    public enum EnumType : byte
    {
        String,
        Int32,
        Boolean
    }
} //eof program
```